# Anaconda stuck on loading applications

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

When starting Anaconda it gets stuck on 'loading applications'

Here's what's displayed when running: conda info

```
active environment : None
   user config file : /Users/ryanovsienko/.condarc
populated config files : /Users/ryanovsienko/.condarc
      conda version : 4.6.7
conda-build version : 3.17.8
     python version : 3.6.8.final.0
   base environment : /Users/ryanovsienko/anaconda  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
      package cache : /Users/ryanovsienko/anaconda/pkgs
                      /Users/ryanovsienko/.conda/pkgs
   envs directories : /Users/ryanovsienko/anaconda/envs
                      /Users/ryanovsienko/.conda/envs
           platform : osx-64
         user-agent : conda/4.6.7 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.6.8 Darwin/18.2.0 OSX/10.14.3
            UID:GID : 501:20
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Here the output from:

```
conda list

# packages in environment at /Users/ryanovsienko/anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_license                  1.1                      py36_1  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py36_0  
anaconda                  custom           py36ha4fed55_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py36_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py36_0  
appnope                   0.1.0            py36hf537a9a_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py36h1de35cc_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
astroid                   2.1.0                    py36_0  
astropy                   3.1.2            py36h1de35cc_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                      py_0  
attrs                     18.2.0           py36h28b3542_0  
babel                     2.6.0                    py36_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0  
backports                 1.0                      py36_1  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py36_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py36_2  
basemap                   1.2.0            py36h0acbc05_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                    py36_1  
bitarray                  0.8.3            py36h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h073222e_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blaze                     0.11.3           py36h02e7a37_0  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py36_0  
bokeh                     1.0.4                    py36_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py36_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36h1d22016_1  
bzip2                     1.0.6                h1de35cc_5  
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
certifi                   2018.11.29               py36_0  
cffi                      1.12.1           py36hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py36_1   
click                     7.0                      py36_0  
cloudpickle               0.8.0                    py36_0   
clyent                    1.2.2                    py36_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py36_0  
conda                     4.6.7                    py36_0  
conda-build               3.17.8                   py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-verify              3.1.1                    py36_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36hd66e5e7_0  
cryptography              2.5              py36ha12b0ac_0  
curl                      7.63.0            ha441bb4_1000  
cycler                    0.10.0           py36hfc81398_0  
cython                    0.29.5           py36h0a44026_0   
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36h1de35cc_1  
dask                      0.16.1                   py36_0  
dask-core                 1.1.2                      py_0   
datashape                 0.5.4                    py36_1  
dbus                      1.13.6               h90a0687_0  
decorator                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
distributed               1.26.0                   py36_0  
django                    2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.14             py36hbfde631_0  
ecdsa                     0.13                     pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.3                      py36_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h1315bdc_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36h1de35cc_2  
filelock                  3.0.10                   py36_0  
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1  
flask-cors                3.0.7                    py36_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
future                    0.17.1                   py36_0  
geckodriver               0.20.1               hfc679d8_1    conda forge
geos                      3.6.2                h5470d99_2  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.4.0            py36h1de35cc_0  
git                       2.20.1          pl526h6951d83_0  
glib                      2.56.2               hd9629dc_0  
glob2                     0.6                      py36_1  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36h6ef4df4_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py36h1de35cc_0  
h5py                      2.7.1            py36h39cdac5_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      py36_0  
imageio                   2.5.0                    py36_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py36_0  
importlib_metadata        0.7                      py36_0  
inflection                0.3.1                    py36_1  
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144  
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py36h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.3.0            py36h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h241746c_0  
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py36_0  
isort                     4.3.8                    py36_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py36_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0  
jedi                      0.13.3                   py36_0 
jinja2                    2.10                     py36_0  
jose                      1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi 
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
jsonpickle                0.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi 
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36hb385e00_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py36_0  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_0  
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py36_0  
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                   py36_0  
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py36_0  
jupyterthemes             0.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
keyring                   18.0.0                   py36_0  
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h0a44026_0  
krb5                      1.16.1               hddcf347_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h1de35cc_2  
lesscpy                   0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libcurl                   7.63.0            h051b688_1000  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2   
libpng                    1.6.36               ha441bb4_0     
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libssh2                   1.8.0                ha12b0ac_4  
libtiff                   4.0.10               hcb84e12_2  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hab757c2_0  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
llvmlite                  0.27.0           py36h8c7ce04_0  
locket                    0.2.0            py36hca03003_1  
lxml                      4.3.1            py36hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2   
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.0.2            py36h54f8f79_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py36h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.1                      144  
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h6b9c3cc_5  
mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py36h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36h27c97d8_0  
more-itertools            5.0.0                    py36_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py36_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py36h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py36_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0  
nbconvert                 5.3.1                    py36_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h827af21_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.2                      py36_1  
nltk                      3.4                      py36_1  
nose                      1.3.7                    py36_2  
notebook                  5.7.4                    py36_0  
numba                     0.36.2          np114py36hc2f221f_0  
numexpr                   2.6.4            py36habcfcfe_0  
numpy                     1.15.4           py36hacdab7b_0  
numpy-base                1.15.4           py36h6575580_0  
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0  
oauthlib                  3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
odo                       0.5.1            py36hc1af34a_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py36_0  
openpyxl                  2.6.0                    py36_0  
openssl                   1.1.1b               h1de35cc_0  
packaging                 19.0                     py36_0  
pandas                    0.24.1           py36h0a44026_0  
pandas-datareader         0.7.0                    py36_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1  
parso                     0.3.4                    py36_0  
partd                     0.3.9                    py36_0  
path.py                   11.5.0                   py36_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py36_0  
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0  
pcre                      8.42                 h378b8a2_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0  
perl                      5.26.2               h4e221da_0  
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py36_0  
pillow                    5.4.1            py36hb68e598_0  
pip                       18.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py36_0  
pluggy                    0.9.0                    py36_0  
ply                       3.11                     py36_0  
proj4                     5.2.0                h0a44026_1  
prometheus_client         0.6.0                    py36_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py36_0  
psutil                    5.5.0            py36h1de35cc_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py36_0  
py                        1.8.0                    py36_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py36h1413db1_2  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py36_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py36_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36h1de35cc_9  
pycryptodome              3.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py36ha12b0ac_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.0                    py36_0  
pygments                  2.3.1                    py36_0  
pylint                    2.2.2                    py36_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.26           py36h0a44026_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.3.1                    py36_0  
pyperclip                 1.5.27                   py36_0   bryanwweber
pyproj                    1.9.6            py36h9c430a6_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h655552a_2  
pyqt5                     5.12                     pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.14                  pypi_0    pypi
pyshp                     2.0.1                    py36_0  
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0  
pytables                  3.4.2            py36hfbd7ab0_2  
pytest                    4.3.0                    py36_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py36h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py36_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py36_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.2                    py36_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py36_0  
python                    3.6.8                haf84260_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py36_0  
python-jose               2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi 
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py36_6  
python-oauth2             1.1.0            py36h28b3542_1  
python-quickbooks         0.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
python.app                2                        py36_9  
pytz                      2018.9                   py36_0  
pywavelets                1.0.1            py36h1d22016_0   
pyyaml                    3.13             py36h1de35cc_0   
pyzmq                     18.0.0           py36h0a44026_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.5.6                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py36_0  
qtpy                      1.6.0                      py_0  
quandl                    3.4.5                    py36_0  
rauth                     0.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-file             1.4.3                    py36_0  
requests-ftp              0.3.1                    py36_1  
requests-oauthlib         0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rope                      0.12.0                   py36_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py36h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.13.1           py36h1de35cc_1  
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36hffbff8c_0  
scipy                     1.0.0            py36h1de22e9_0  
seaborn                   0.8.1            py36h595ecd9_0  
selenium                  3.141.0          py36h1de35cc_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0  
setuptools                40.8.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2  
simplejson                3.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36hf20db9d_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py36h0a44026_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py36_0  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h6c7b616_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py36_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py36_0  
soupsieve                 1.7.1                    py36_0  
sphinx                    1.8.4                    py36_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py36_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py36_1  
spyder                    3.3.3                    py36_0  
spyder-kernels            0.4.2                    py36_0  
sqlalchemy                1.2.18           py36h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               ha441bb4_0  
statsmodels               0.8.0            py36h9c68fc9_0  
strict-rfc3339            0.7                      pypi_0    pypi
sympy                     1.3                      py36_0  
tblib                     1.3.2            py36hda67792_0  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py36_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0  
tornado                   5.1.1            py36h1de35cc_0  
tqdm                      4.31.1                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h65bd3ce_0  
typed-ast                 1.3.1            py36h1de35cc_0  
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36he531d66_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py36_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h8c6ec74_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.33.1                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py36_0  
wrapt                     1.11.1           py36h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py36_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py36_0  
xlsxwriter                1.1.5                    py36_0  
xlwings                   0.15.3                   py36_0  
xlwt                      1.2.0            py36h5ad1178_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      0.1.3                    py36_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

have tried
    conda update conda
    conda update --all
    conda update anaconda-navigator
    conda update python.app
    conda update anaconda-client
    anaconda-navigator --reset
    conda update navigator-updater
    conda update launcher

Not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened, just started working again. *sigh*